# Erased root trash but still getting no memory

Tags: 10.04, apache2, php, log, trash

I was coding my site on Apache Server. Suddenly an error came and I got the warning

> This computer has only 1.3 GB remaining.

I knew that this was because of the log file in **/var/log/apache2/subins/error.log**.

I opened the folder in **root** and the file size of the log was 17 GB. I deleted the error file. I went on to the **root trash** folder to delete the log file permanently. I deleted the files and info folder in the 'root trash' folder. So I had erased the root trash folder. But things got wrong. I still get the warning

> This computer has only 1.3 GB remaining

I think I did the wrong way to empty root trash.

I used **Disk Usage Analyzer** to find the log file to permanently delete . But the software didn't showed the file. What happened to the folder I deleted in 'root trash'?

Here's the screenshot of Disk Usage Analyzer after the search.
[image]

**UPDATE:** Now my computer memory is 1 KB after I run the web page again in which the error showed.

Output of `df -T -H`:

```
Filesystem    Type     Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7     ext4      40G    38G    21k 100% /
none      devtmpfs     455M   291k   455M   1% /dev
none         tmpfs     460M   3.4M   456M   1% /dev/shm
none         tmpfs     460M   312k   459M   1% /var/run
```

Comment: Maybe it is a different file?

Comment: The log file's size is 17 GB! I have no other file in my computer more than 3 GB.

Comment: But if the file isn't there anymore and there is still too little space, I would suspect another file?

Comment: Updated the post. See the image - http://i.stack.imgur.com/0PLmF.png

Comment: please post the output for `df -T -H`

Comment: @gajdipajti http://pastebin.com/T5kZuR8P

Comment: ok, now please run the Disk Usage Analyzer with the `gksudo baobab` command for the / partition. And post the picture here.

Comment: @gajdipajti The picture is the window from command gksudo baobab

Comment: It is strange, because df and baobab should show the same size for /. I have no clue how to solve this. Maybe you should just reboot, and see what happens.

Comment: Also you can force the filesystem check comman at boot time if you shut down with `shutdown -rF now` command. After the errors are corrected, you can recheck your system with baobab.

Comment: Thank you @gajdipajti . I rebooted and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my computer as told by [gajdipajti](https://askubuntu.com/users/40445/gajdipajti)

I restarted my computer and the problem is solved. I got the lost memory back. Now I have **19.6 GB** free as before the memory increase of log file.

So I think the solution is **Restart the computer**.

Comment: normally or with forced fsck?

Comment: @gajdipajti normally.

Answer (score 0):

try and look for big files in your system

```
find / -type f -size +10000k -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

then delete them and make some room for other files.

Comment: I still can't find the big file. I got a maximum of 300 MB size file when searching for big files using the mentioned command.

Comment: try the following, it will scan your whole system for large files not only in your current directory find / -type f -size +10000k -exec ls -lh {} \;

Comment: I still can't find the big file. I got a maximum of 300 MB size file when searching for big files using the mentioned command- Same thing.

Comment: I tried it on my PC, and it shows files up to 10GB, so the max file size in your PC is 300MB, or you are doing something wrong :)